# window.open opening single link

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, window.open

I am onto making a tuition management program in which I am dealing with the given JSON file named data.json:

```
{
  "9 Standard": [
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/",
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
  ],
  "9 Applied": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ],
  "10 Standard": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ],
  "10 Applied": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ],
  "11 Standard": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ],
  "11 Applied": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ],
  "12 Standard": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ],
  "12 Applied": [
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+fonts&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN950IN950&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "https://byjus.com/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths/"
  ]
}
```

Now the above JSON file contains links which teacher wants to open instantly to start his class. So I am trying to make such arrangements as follows:

Screenshot of the program which I desire to make

[image: Screenshot]

Code that I wrote to create the buttons while the computer goes through data of data.json

```
<script>
      fetch("data.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function (classes) {
          console.log(classes);
          Object.keys(classes).forEach(function func(class_data) {
            let btn = document.createElement("button");
            btn.innerHTML = class_data;
            btn.name = class_data;
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
            btn.className = "button";
            btn.onclick = function () {
              links = classes[class_data];
              links.forEach(func);
              console.log(links);
              function func(link) {
                console.log(link);
                window.open(link, class_data);
              }
            };
          });
        });
    </script>
```

I expected every button to open 2 windows, but only 1 gets opened. So as per [this site](https://javascript.info/popup-windows), I replaced the line `window.open(link, class_data);` of code by `setTimeout(() => window.open(link), 3000);`, but still only one window gets opened. I am confused about how to overcome this problem. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Lux for helping, the program works now. For those who are stuck in the same problem, I would recommend them to click on the 3 dots at the upper right corner of your google window, then click on `settings` and type `Pop-ups and redirects` in `search settings` . Now google will guide you to the exact page where you can change this setting, and over there, just change `Pop-ups and redirects` to `Allowed` and now you would find window.open command opening multiple windows.